# Adding objects to hashmap as keys which only equals method implemented

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the below class which only equals is overridden,

```
class S {

    String txt = null;

    S(String i) {
        txt = i;
    }       

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        S cc = (S) o;
        if (this.txt.equals(cc.txt)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Default hash code will be called
    /*public int hashCode(){
        return txt.hashCode();
    }*/

}
```

I add this class objects to a hash map as below,

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            S s1 = new S("a");
            S s2 = new S("b");
            S s3 = new S("a");

            Map m = new HashMap();
            m.put(s1, "v11");
            m.put(s2, "v22");
            m.put(s3, "v33");

            System.out.println(m.size());
            System.out.println(m.get(s1));
    }
```

Can explain the result 3 and v11 is printed? Shouldnt the value v11 of s1 is replace by v33 because same equals key is put as s3?

Comment: `#equals` will only be called if two objects have the same hash code (= they would be in the same "bucket"). Have you tried to read something about the behaviour of a `HashMap`? For example this: [Understanding the workings of equals and hashCode in a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1894377)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must override `hashCode` as well. if `a.equals(b)`, `a.hashCode()` must be equal to `b.hashCode()`. The implementation of `hashCode` determines in which bucket the entry will be stored. If you don't override `hashCode`, you might have two equal keys stored in two different buckets.

Add this to your `S` class :

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    if (txt == null)
        return 0;
    return txt.hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The situation you decribe is a violation of the contract. If you override `equals()` in such a way as to break the contract of `hashCode(),` you must override `hashCode()` as well.