# Use for each loop to print objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist, foreach

so I need to use a method to print out the contents of my rectangle and circle objects. I want them formatted something like this

```
GeometricObject [color=red, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Feb 11 12:21:51 EST
2015]
Circle [ radius= 4.0 Area=50.27 Perimeter=25.13 ]
```

I was given the method signature so i must use it, I have tried two different ways to test whether the object is either a rectangle or circle and then take the correct action but i cannot get them to print anything (I believe I may be missing something from my public class hw2redo more specifically my recreateObject method). The logic I was aiming for is that if the object is equal to a circle (in my recreateObject method I have two return signatures of either circle or rectangle) then it would use the the printCircle method in the Circle class, but no output. My second logical path was if the objects list contained the word "Rectangle" anywhere in it, of course that would mean it is a rectangle object and would access the printRectangle method in the Rectangle class but again nothing. However, I will note if i just use 
`((Circle) o).printCircle();` 
for example, it will invoke the printCircle method for all of my circle objects and throw an exception once it reaches my first rectangle object (I think I'm close!).

```
private static void showObjects(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list) {

         for(GeometricObject o : list) {

             if ((o.equals("Circle")))
             ((Circle) o).printCircle();
             if (o.equals(list.contains("Rectangle")))
             ((Rectangle) o).printRectangle();
         }
    }
```

Here is the entirety of my code if your interested.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class hw2redo 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

          GeometricObject g = null;
          File diskFile = new File("file.txt");
          Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(diskFile);
          ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
          while(diskScanner.hasNext()){
              String geolist = diskScanner.nextLine();
              g = recreateObject(geolist);

              list.add(g);

          }
          diskScanner.close();
         /* while (diskScanner.hasNext()) {
              String list = diskScanner.nextLine();
              g = recreateObject(list);
          }
          diskScanner.close();*/
          showObjects(list);
       }





    private static GeometricObject recreateObject(String data) {

          String[] list = data.split(",");
          String geoObject = list[0];

          if (geoObject.equals("Circle")) {
             String color = list[1];
             boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(list[2]); 
             double radius = Double.valueOf(list[3]);
             return new Circle(radius, color, filled);
          }

          if (geoObject.equals("Rectangle")) {
             String color = list[1];
             boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(list[2]);
             double height = Double.valueOf(list[3]);
             double width = Double.valueOf(list[4]);
             return new Rectangle(width, height, color, filled);
          }
        return null;


       }

    private static void showObjects(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list) {

         for(GeometricObject o : list) {

             if ((o.equals("Circle")))
             ((Circle) o).printCircle();
             if (o.equals(list.contains("Rectangle")))
             ((Rectangle) o).printRectangle();
         }
    }
}

abstract class GeometricObject {
       private String color = "white";
       private boolean filled;
       private java.util.Date dateCreated;
       private String data;

      /** Construct a default geometric object */
      public GeometricObject() {
          super();
     dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
     //this.data = data;
      }


    /** Construct a geometric object with the specified color
     * and filled value */
     public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
     super();
     dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
     this.color = color;
     this.filled = filled;

     }

     /** Return color */
     public String getColor() {
     return color;
     }

     /** Set a new color */
     public void setColor(String color) {
     this.color = color;
     }

     /** Return filled. Since filled is boolean,
     its getter method is named isFilled */
     public boolean isFilled() {
     return filled;
     }

     /** Set a new filled */
     public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
     this.filled = filled;
     }

     /** Get dateCreated */
     public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
     return dateCreated;
     }

     /** Return a string representation of this object */
     public String toString() {
     return  "GeometricObject [color=" + color +", filled="+ filled + ", dateOfCreation=" + dateCreated +
             "]\n";

     }
     }
class Circle extends GeometricObject
{
private double radius;

public Circle() {
    super();
    radius = 1;

}


public Circle(double radius,
String color, boolean filled) {
    super(color, filled);
this.radius = radius;
setColor(color);
setFilled(filled);
}

/** Return radius */
public double getRadius() {
return radius;
}

/** Set a new radius */
public void setRadius(double radius) {
this.radius = radius;
}

/** Return area */
public double getArea() {
return radius * radius * Math.PI;
}

/** Return diameter */
public double getDiameter() {
return 2 * radius;
}

/** Return perimeter */
public double getPerimeter() {
return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
}

/** Print the circle info */
public void printCircle() {
System.out.println("The circle is created " + getDateCreated() +
" and the radius is " + radius);
}
}


class Rectangle extends GeometricObject {
private double width;
private double height;

public Rectangle() {
    super();
}



public Rectangle(
double width, double height, String color, boolean filled) {
    super(color, filled);
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
setColor(color);
setFilled(filled);
}

/** Return width */
public double getWidth() {
return width;
}

/** Set a new width */
public void setWidth(double width) {
this.width = width;
}

/** Return height */
public double getHeight() {
return height;
}

/** Set a new height */
public void setHeight(double height) {
this.height = height;
}

/** Return area */
public double getArea() {
return width * height;
}

/** Return perimeter */
public double getPerimeter() {
return 2 * (width + height);
}
public void printRectangle() {
System.out.println("The circle is created " + getDateCreated() +
" and the radius is " + width);
}
}
```

My file.txt (the objects I'm trying to recreate) conatins

```
Circle,green,false,4.0
Circle,blue,false,2.0
Circle,blue,true,7.0
Rectangle,orange,true,10.0,6.0
Rectangle,green,false,5.0,11.0
Rectangle,red,true,14.0,12.0
```

Any help or hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Comment: `o.equals(list.contains("Rectangle"))` is flat-out incorrect (as is your other `equals` call); you're going to try to see if two completely unrelated objects are equivalent, which would fail.

Comment: How are they completely unrelated? I'm trying to see if the object is a Circle? @Makoto

Comment: Well...the string `"Circle"` isn't an instance of `GeometricObject`...and neither is a `boolean`.

Comment: Is there a way to check if an actual object is an instance of GeometricObject (I've been going through the methods in the ArrayList Class my book provides but cannot find anything to check for objects)? @Makoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `.equals()` method overridden in your code so that you can use 
    `if ((o.equals("Circle")))` in `showObjects()` method.

You need to **either** handle `.equals()` method appropriately in your code **or** you can use

```
 if ( o instanceof Circle)
```

instead of `if ((o.equals("Circle")))` in `showObjects()` method. You may need to do the same for your other objects (like `Rectangle` mentioned above) too.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what i was trying to accomplish. If i may ask, is this a normal or preferred method or would one rather  override the .equals() method. Again i appreciate the help!

Comment: @RiFF RAFF, To accomplish what you are trying to do (just identify the type), you are better off with this approach than overriding the equals method. `equals()` serves a greater purpose. Please find a relevant link below on the same. 
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17

Comment: Another related SO link (on `equals()` and `hashCode()` ) for you to read :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894377/understanding-the-workings-of-equals-and-hashcode-in-a-hashmap

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use a method to print out the content
>   s of my rectangle and circle objects.

```
Circle [ radius= 4.0 Area=50.27 Perimeter=25.13 ]
```

> Any help or hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a hint for `Circle` class. Use the following method to print circle:

```
public void printCircle() {
        System.out.println("Circle [" +
                "radius=" + radius +
                "  Area=" + getArea() +
                "  Perimeter=" + getPerimeter() +
                ' ]');
    }
```

I have not checked your logic as you need to learn it yourself :).