# Get Integer value from key Object of hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

In one of my classes say Test, in static block of it; i am constructing map using an object of type BakidRangeid as key and Integer as value. My hashmap declaration looks as below.

```
public static HashMap<BakidRangeid, Integer> mapBankIdRangeIdToConfId = new HashMap<BakidRangeid, Integer> ();
```

And BakidRangeid class looks like

```
public class BakidRangeid {

private int bankId;
private int rangeId;

public int getBankId() {
    return bankId;
}
public void setBankId(int bankId) {
    this.bankId = bankId;
}
public int getRangeId() {
    return rangeId;
}
public void setRangeId(int rangeId) {
    this.rangeId = rangeId;
}
```

}

When i am trying to get the value from hashmap mapBankIdRangeIdToConfId by setting instance of an BakidRangeid, i get NullpointerException inspite of the object with values of bankid and rangeid, which i am passing is present in the hashmap. I guess i will have to override equals and hashcode methods of my BakidRangeid class. Anyone kindly confirm. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that you need to implement `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: As you stated, did you try overriding the  hashcode method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override equals method of class BakidRangeid before using as a key in hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use `hashCode()` and `equals()` method in BakidRangeid class.

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894377/understanding-the-workings-of-equals-and-hashcode-in-a-hashmap)