# Group by for a list of int arrays

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of int arrays. I want to group that by unique arrays.

```
int[] array1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
int[] array2 = new int[]{1, 2, 3}; //array1 = array2 
int[] array3 = new int[]{0, 2, 3};

List<int[]> test = new ArrayList<>();

test.add(array1);
test.add(array2);
test.add(array3);

test.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It groups as if any array was unique:

```
{1, 2, 3} - 1
{1, 2, 3} - 1 
{0, 2, 3} - 1
```

I expect:

```
{1, 2, 3} - 2
{0, 2, 3} - 1
```

What can I do?

Comment: replace `Function.identity()` with something that actually compares the *content* of your arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It groups as if any array was unique:

And it is the case.
You would indeed have some difficulties to implement it whatever the way : built-in `Collector`s such as `groupingBy()` and `toMap()` or loop as two arrays with the same content are not equals in terms of `equals()` (and `hashCode()` too).
You should consider to use `List<Integer>` for this use case instead of `int[]`.

For example :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] array2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // array1 = array2
        int[] array3 = new int[] { 0, 2, 3 };

        List<List<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<>();

        test.add(Arrays.stream(array1)
                       .boxed()
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        test.add(Arrays.stream(array2)
                       .boxed()
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        test.add(Arrays.stream(array3)
                       .boxed()
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        Map<List<Integer>, Long> map = test.stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(map);    
    }
```

Output :

> {[0, 2, 3]=1, [1, 2, 3]=2}

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Map<Integer, Long> res = test.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Arrays::hashCode, Collectors.counting()));
```

Please notice that in the map instead of actual array as the key you will have array hash code.
If you want to have actual array as a key - you should wrap it in the class with equals/hashcode implemented based on array content.

Comment: grouping by hash code will probably work fine 99% the time, but bite you horribly once two non-identical arrays produce the same hashcode

Comment: Correct - that is just for illustration how the grouping works, not the definitive solution - especially that resulting map is not much useful (as it does not have original array) - thus suggestion of wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list and java8 streams.

```java
Map<List<Integer>, Long> mapList = Stream.of(array1, array2, array3)
        .map(Arrays::stream)
        .map(IntStream::boxed)
        .map(stream -> stream.collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

If you want the `Map<int[], Long>` you can continue after the `collect()` above like.

```
        // ... collect ...
        .entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey()
                   .stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray(), Entry::getValue));
        // returns Map<int[], Long>
```

Still I think that the question emphasizes the use of arrays. You can create a wrapper class for the `int[]` object.

This is just an example for the int array wrapper, even though a more complex class can be used, with something like the factory pattern to allow the use of all array primitives and even array of objects.

```java
public class IntArray {
    private final int[] array;
    private IntArray(final int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
    public static IntArray wrap(final int[] array) {
        return new IntArray(array);
    }
    public int[] unwrap() {
        return array;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof IntArray
                && Arrays.equals(((IntArray) obj).array, array);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(array);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }
}
```

Here the `wrap(..)` method is optional, `IntArray::new` can be used instead, also the `toString()` method is optional to allow the conversion of the internal array to string without the need un unwrap.

The necessary methods are `equals(..)` and `hashcode()` because they are required for the map to work properly.

Here is more info about it.

[Understanding the workings of equals and hashCode in a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894377/understanding-the-workings-of-equals-and-hashcode-in-a-hashmap)

Finally it can be used like.

```java
Map<IntArray, Long> mapArray = Stream.of(array1, array2, array3)
        .map(IntArray::wrap)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

And again if you want the array as key of the map (as a `Map<int[], Long>`) you can do the following (note that in this case, a new array is not created, it just uses the first unique array that it finds).

```java
        // ... collect ...
        .entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey()
                   .unwrap(), Entry::getValue));
        // returns Map<int[], Long>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider converting your `int arrays` to Lists then you could introduce custom logic inside `collect` as follows:

```
test
                        .parallelStream()
                        .map(array -> Arrays.stream(array)
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        )
                        .collect(HashMap::new,
                                (HashMap<List<Integer>, Integer> map, List<Integer> list) -> {
                                    if (map.containsKey(list)) {
                                        map.put(list, map.get(list) + 1);
                                    } else {
                                        map.put(list, 1);
                                    }
                                },
                                (HashMap<List<Integer>, Integer> map1, HashMap<List<Integer>, Integer> map2) -> {
                                    map2.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                                        if (map1.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
                                            map1.put(entry.getKey(), map1.get(entry.getKey()) + 1);
                                        } else {
                                            map1.put(entry.getKey(), 1);
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                        )
```

To understand what is happening here see the definition of the collect method below:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
                  BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
                  BiConsumer<R, R> combiner)
```

Here,

`Supplier` is basically the returned type.

`accumulator` is the accumulator bi consumer, notice how I have accumulated the results.

`combiner` only works if you are doing parallel execution. Hence, I combined the results of parallel execution such that our output remains same. You could simply think like we have used `Divide and Conquer` here.

This is rather very powerful when you have exhausted all your efforts on available `Collectors` and you have to write a custom solution.